# Debezium: double values serialization/deserializtion issue

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I am facing issue with getting Double values from a mysql table via CDC using Debezium connector with mysql.

Below is the connector props:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "10",
    "database.hostname": "mysql.default",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "debezium",
    "database.password": "debezium",
    "database.server.name": "mydb", 
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.mysql",
    "table.whitelist": "mydb.request",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "decimal.handing.mode":"double",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "topic.creation.default.retention.ms": 86400000,
    "snapshot.locking.mode": "none",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor":3,
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": 3
  }
}
```

The above config generated topic with name `mydb.mydb.request`, when I tried to read that topic via CLI console consumer, I got all double values deserialized as strings (total_amount_without_discount, total_amount, discount_amount) as below:

```
{
    "id": 123,
.
.
.
    "total_amount_without_discount": "Al/Q",
    "total_amount": "AlqI",
    "discount_amount": "BUg="
}
```

Can anyone point where the problem is, or what could be the problem with the configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a typo in the
 `"decimal.handling.mode":"double"` field.

My assumption, The problem is due to the fact that the default value for the above config field is `precise` which based on the docs it maps it to bytes (Literal type) (https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-decimal-types)

Note: `double` is not mentioned under confluent docs, but it only exists under debezium docs.

here is confluent docs
https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.1/connect/debezium-connect-mysql/mysql_source_connector_config.html